# 8.16 Z lab Zylabs Python

Tags: python

Statistics are often calculated with varying amounts of input data. Write a program that takes any number of non-negative floating-point numbers as input, and outputs the max and average, respectively.

Output the max and average with two digits after the decimal point.

Ex: If the input is: 14.25 25 0 5.75

the output is: 25.00 11.25

```
user_input = input()

tokens = user_input.split()  

nums = []                    
for token in tokens:        
    nums.append(int(token))

avg = sum(nums) / len(nums) 
print(int(avg), max(nums))
```

Works with whole numbers, not decimals.
Could someone show me how to correctly do it?

Comment: _Works with whole numbers_ Of course, because you are converting the input numbers with `int()`, which produces integer values.

Comment: user_input = input()

tokens = user_input.split()

nums = [float(t) for t in tokens]

avg = sum(nums) / len(nums) 
print(max(nums), int(avg))

Answer (score 0):

Convert input strings to `float` types not `int`:

```
nums = [float(t) for t in tokens] # Using a comprehension lets you do it in one line
```

Comment: I did this: user_input = input()

tokens = user_input.split()

nums = [float(t) for t in tokens]

avg = sum(nums) / len(nums) 
print(max(nums), int(avg)) It gave me the max of 25.0 and the avg 11. Am I missing something the avg should be 11.25

Comment: @DarrenRobinson You're printing `int(avg)`, so of course it prints a whole number.  Why are you doing that?  Just print `avg`.

Comment: I didn't see that until a few minutes after I made that comment. I did fix it though.